# Why is my published feed not available for extended period of time?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I've noticed lately that newly published private (upstream feed) NPM packages are not available right away and sometimes takes anywhere from hours to days to become available.

My feed is scoped and looks similar to:
`@some-feed-ui:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/account/_packaging/some-feed@Local/npm/registry/`

Could this issue be related to the scope not matching the feed or possibly using `@Local/npm/registry/` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer in the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#metadata-cached-from-upstream-sources). Which also, indicates you can't access a newly published upstream feed for 24 hours.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: This is a limitation of how upstreams are currently designed. We were hoping to improve it in Q1 but weren't able to. We're going to try again in Q3.

Comment: @AlexMullans is there a feature work item I can follow on this work?